# Limit of sum with binomial coefficient

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Prove that: 
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\sqrt{{n\choose k}}=0$$
I completely don't know how to approach. Is it very difficult?

Comment: It is reasonable to believe that behaviour for odd, even $n$ is not too dissimilar, and for odd it is always $0$.

Comment: One way is to consider integral: $$\frac{1}{2i} \int_\gamma \sqrt{ \frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (n+1 - z) \Gamma (z+)}} \frac{1}{\sin \pi z} \, dz$$ where $\gamma$ is a rectangle with corners in $-\frac{1}{2} \pm ib$ and $n+\frac{1}{2} \pm ib$ than take limit $n, b \to +\infty$ which requires some manipulations along the road.

Comment: The pieces of a complete answer can be collected starting from [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/85013/alternating-sum-of-square-roots-of-binomial-coefficients).

Answer (score 2):

First note that $f(z)=\frac{\sin \pi z}{\pi z(1-z)(1-\frac{z}{2})\cdots(1-\frac{z}{n})}$ satisfies $f(z)=\binom{n}{k}$ for any integer $k$.

Because $f(z)$ has no zeros in $-1<Re(z)<n+1$,$\sqrt{f(z)}$ (taken as positive at the origin) is analytic there.  By the Residue Theorem, we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k} \sqrt{\binom{n}{k}}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C} \sqrt{f(z)}\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi z}dz,$$ where $C$ is any contour in  $-1<Re(z)<n+1$ which winds *once* about each integer $0,1,\ldots,n$ and *never* about any other integer.

Suppose we let $C=C_{M}$ be the rectangle formed by the lines $Re(z)=-\frac{1}{2}$, $Re(z)=n+1/2$, and $Im(z)=\pm M.$  Then

$$\int_{C_M} \sqrt{f(z)}\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi z}dz=\int_{C_{M}}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\,dz}{\sqrt{z(1-z)(1-z/2)\cdots(1-z/n)\sin \pi z}}$$

and letting $M\rightarrow \infty$, we conclude that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k} \sqrt{\binom{n}{k}}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\left[\int_{-1/2+i \infty}^{-1/2- i \infty}+\int_{n+1/2-i \infty}^{n+1/2+i \infty}\sqrt{f(z)}\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi z}dz\right].$$

Since the integrand is invariant (aside from a $\pm$ sign) under the substotution $z\rightarrow n - z$, we need only estimate the first integral.  Now, when $Re(z)=-\frac{1}{2}$,

\begin{align*}
|z(1-z)(1-z/2)\cdots(1-z/n)|
&\ge \frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(1+\frac{1}{4}\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right) \\
&\ge\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+1}\sqrt{1+1/2}\cdots\sqrt{1+1/n}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{2}.
\end{align*}

and so the first integral is bounded by

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt[4]{n+1}}\int_{Re(z)=-1/2}|\frac{dz}{\sqrt{\sin\pi z}}|\le\frac{A}{\sqrt[4]{n}}.$$

Hence $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k} \sqrt{\binom{n}{k}}\rightarrow0$$ as $n\rightarrow\infty.$

[The problem seems to have originated with D. J. Newman, who posed this as Problem 81-7 in the *SIAM Review*.  A more complicated proof, as well as a discussion of generalizations, appears on pp. 155-156 of *Problems in Applied Mathematics: Selections from SIAM Review* edited by Murray Klamkin (SIAM, 1990).  The proof given above can be found on pp. 151-152 of *Complex Analysis* (*Second Edition*) by Bak and Newman (Springer, 1997).]

Answer (score 0):

The terms for $n$ odd are zero by cancelling the binomial at $k$ and $n-k$ since the signs are opposite.

When $n$ is even, the terms do not seem to have a limit.